# How to change listview adapter in section setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have listview with some listadapter after click on item from list I'd like to reload list with new data, change  adapter's contests.

I use this in setOnItemClickListener, but I get error: "Type The constructor ArrayAdapter(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int, ArrayList) is undefined"

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Data.user.getChosen_rest()));
```

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glendon's answer is probably the right one. Nevertheless, in case you really need to change the adapter for some reason, you need to pass the right `Context` instance to the first argument of the constructor.

You can extend OnClickListener and add a field mContext to it, to which you will assign the current Activity. Then , use it as:

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Data.user.getChosen_rest()));
```

Alternatively, if the listener is an inner class of the Activity, you can use:

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Data.user.getChosen_rest()));
```

Comment: thanks Aleadam your answer works for me:) And one more question after click my adapter and things on list are changing. I'd like to have option go back after press back button, what is the easiest way to get done this task?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by go back. Anyhow, that looks like a completely different question. Please, consider posting a new one with a better description of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426) should get you headed in the right direction.  If you can transform your initial ArrayAdapter using `add()`, `remove()`, `insert()`, or `clear()`, you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to reload it.

**Edit**

Actually, to better address your error, try replacing

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Data.user.getChosen_rest()));
```

with

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NameOfActivity.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Data.user.getChosen_rest()));
```

first.

Comment: It is, depending on where is the listener. I added the same approach before seeing your edit.

Comment: When I clear my adapter and try to add new string or "Re-create the ArrayAdapter with the new List data" I get error mentioned at beginning `Type The constructor ArrayAdapter(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int, ArrayList) is undefined"`

Comment: BTW, `NameOfJavaFile` could be the name of the class extending OnClickListener, it's not clear that yo're referring to the Activity.